# Pull to refresh Crash my application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos-carbon

I have an Application, that takes Restaurants from shared Google Api and displays it in a table view.Then i use

> Carbon-kit

for pull to refresh content of tableview

```
    refresh = [[CarbonSwipeRefresh alloc] initWithScrollView:self.tblRest];
    //[refresh setMarginTop:120];
    [refresh setColors:@[[UIColor blueColor], [UIColor redColor], [UIColor orangeColor], [UIColor greenColor]]];
    [self.view addSubview:refresh];

    [refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(pullToRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

When i scroll my table and try to refresh it, It gives me below error:-

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds for empty array'`

please help me for this error.
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: this is because you are clearing your array while reloading...

Comment: @Viraj Padsala given code is not causing crash in your application, code written in `pullToRefresh:` method is causing crash.

Comment: @ Dipen As fahim said i init my array each and evry time of refresh that cause my app crash...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you must be initializing your array again while refreshing.